# Facebook API access outside of apps.facebook.com

Tags: facebook

I am attempting to build a website that utilizes facebook auth based setting created through facebook.com/developers

Can I access a `user’s wall (to post), multi friend selector and other elements` if the website is hosted outside of facebook.com (apps.facebook.com) realm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) through [php sdk](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/), [js sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) or your own legacy one

Answer (score 2):

You must require special permissions to post user's wall. Use a standard api mechanism to get access_token from user. Make sure user accepted the application permissions requirements such as offline_access, publish_stream etc.

```
public function friend_off()
{
    $home_view = 'offline';
$this->load->library('facebook',array(
      'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->where('status', 'A');
        $db_user = $this->db->get('users');

        //$db_user = $this->db->where('access_pass',$val)); 
        $row = $db_user->result();

        //print_r($row);            
        //friends list
        $post =  array(

                'from' => array(
                    'access_token' => '1302623452|1212291707|Dgz0FpB0wL0n5PYLy2x--5iGRVo',
                    'name' => 'Syama Varyar',
                    'id'   => '100002653867222'
                ),
                'to' => array(
                    'name' => 'Vishnu Jayendran',
                    'id'   => '558987909'
                ),

                'caption' => 'Test Caption',
                'description' => 'Test Description',
                'picture' => 'http://www.najeem.com/bird-2003.gif',
                'message' => 'Test Message >>  '. date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

                );
        $friends = $this->facebook->api('/100002653867222/friends?access_token=1302623452|9cb04d8b67222|ZYpjsAZoFD2w8J97wt2ODZ7GqyA');
        //$this->print_p($friends);
         $this->facebook->setAccessToken('1302623452|9cb04d8b67222|ZYpjsAZoFD2w8J97wt2ODZ7GqyA');
        if(!($res = $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $post)))
        {
        $errors= error_get_last(); 
                      echo "Facebook publish error: ".$errors['type'];
                      echo "<br />\n".$errors['message']; 
        }
    }
```